# How to configure Natural Docs to support the Lua language?

Tags: documentation, lua

Natural Docs is a documentation generator that supports several languages. But one of those, is not Lua.
Natural Docs has a language configuration file that allows it to add new languages.

So far, I have added to my configuration file the following lines:

```
Language: Lua
  Extension: lua
  Line Comment: -- //
  Block Comment: [[ ]] --[[ --]] --[[ ]]
  Function Prototype Enders: end \n
  Variable Prototype Ender: \n
```

But after running Natural Docs, the documentation just shows an empty web page.
I've been looking through the internet for a solution, but I've only found different configurations for the "Languages.txt" file (different Function prototype enders, block comments symbols, etc)

I haven't modifying anything, besides that, from the default settings.

Am I missing something else?

Comment: Single line comments are introduced with `--`. Block comments begin with `--[[` and end with `]]`. However, note that the block comment is based on the long string notation which does not nest. To permit nesting, the notation allows for zero or more `=` to appear between the two open square brackets, and a matching number of `=` between the two close square brackets. This is often difficult to express in simple configuration files. Long strings open with `[[` (with optional `=`) and continue to `]]` (with matching `=`) including any newlines.

Comment: Did anyone found a solution for that? I have the same problem with an own defined language.